# Não consigo acessar uma url, nem por inteiro nem por slug

Tags: django, django-templates

Estou fazendo um curso de Django que usa como estudo uma plataforma simplemooc, mas parei numa aula em que ao tentar acessar os detalhes do curso que está em uma url separada numa lista dinâmica, não há mudança na página, continua na listagem dos cursos sem qualquer alteração, a página só recarrega. Tentei criar através do Course.objects.create, mas nada também. Não importa o que coloque após o **/** em **127.0.0.1:8000/cursos/**, seja inteiro, a slug ou qualquer outro valor, nada muda.

O link do primeiro curso no bd está como: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/courses/course/13/change/

Estou achando que seja algo com a expressão regular do urls.py do courses ou algum import faltando. Qual problema?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Course
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    templateName='courses/index.html'
    context = {
        'courses': courses
    }
    return render(request,templateName, context)
def details(request,pk):
    course = Course.objects.get(pk=pk)
    templateName= 'courses/details.html'
    context = {
        'course':course
    }
    return render(request,templateName, context)
```

urls.py do courses:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'index',name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'details', name='details'),
]
```

urls.py do simplemooc:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from simplemooc.core import views as coreViews
from simplemooc.courses import views as coursesViews
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^contato/', coreViews.contact, name="contact"),
    url(r'^cursos/', coursesViews.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^$', coreViews.home, name="home"),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta editar para essa url , uma que você tem semelhante a ela no courses: url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'details', name='details'). Sem o ^ no começo..

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o path ao invés do url? É bem mais simples a escrita, por exemplo:

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.random_view, name="random"),
]
```

Você pode fazer o include do seu app também da seguinte maneira:
Na pasta do seu app crie o arquivo "urls.py", na página do seu projeto use o include assim:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learn.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Então, já tentei usar o path, mas dá alguns erros como `ImportError: cannot import name 'path'`. Isto porque estou utilizando a versão 1.11 do Django e não a nova 2.0.